# iOS use a c++ completion in objective C

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

**EXAMPLE PROJECT REPO**
https://github.com/iamZoltanVaradi/PingPong

In my app i have the following typedef in a c++ header:

```
typedef void (*OnComplete)(const std::string &successString, const std::string &failureString);
```

I put it in a function like this.

```
void PingPong::requestPingPongWithBlock(const string text,  OnComplete completion)
{
    string successString = string();
    string errorString = string();

    if (text.compare("ping") == 0)
    {
        successString = "success ping";
    }
    else
    {
        errorString = "failure pong";
    }

    completion(successString, errorString);
}
```

and it's been called in a function:

```
- (void)requestPingPongWithText:(NSString*)text completion:(OnComplete) compblock{

    PingPong::requestPingPongWithBlock([text UTF8String],compblock);
}
```

but when i call it like this:

```
[self requestPingPongWithText:ping completion:^(const std::string &successString, const std::string &failureString) {

   if (!successString.empty()) {

     NSLog(@"block ping");
   }
   else if (!failureString.empty()) {

     NSLog(@"block pong");
   }
}];
```

i get the following error:

> cannot initialize a parameter of type 'OnComplete' (aka 'void
>   (*)(const std::string &, const std::string &)') with an rvalue of type
>   'void (^)(const std::string &, const std::string &)'

How can i resolve this error?

Comment: I don't believe function pointers and blocks are compatible (since blocks are objects and functions are not). I think you're going to have to create an actual function, and since your usage lacks any apparent context (with which you could have provided the block object), your only solution to call the right block might be a static variable. Messy all around.

Comment: Are you declaring `OnComplete` as `extern "C"`? The linkage property of `OnComplete` may be preventing the conversion.

Comment: I didn't but after i did (by adding extern "C" above the typedef's line) the compiler fails with the same message.

Comment: I updloaded the link to repo where the mentioned project is. Thanks for everyone who takes a look at it.

Comment: To emphasise what mah said: blocks and functional pointers **are explicitly not compatible**. They're both logically and structurally very different things.

Comment: With the help of the accepted answer i did manage to get it done. Check the repo in the description for the working prototype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how you could use blocks here. A fast attempt didn't work out too well for me. However you can use this (it uses my objc_callback wrapper):
**[EDIT] it does work with blocks if you use c++11's std::function. See code below.**

```
#include <string>
// #include <boost/function.hpp> // older c++ with boost
#include <functional> // c++11

template<typename Signature> class objc_callback;

template<typename R, typename... Ts>
class objc_callback<R(Ts...)>
{
public:
    typedef R (*func)(id, SEL, Ts...);

    objc_callback(SEL sel, id obj)
    : sel_(sel)
    , obj_(obj)
    , fun_((func)[obj methodForSelector:sel])
    {
    }

    inline R operator ()(Ts... vs)
    {
        return fun_(obj_, sel_, vs...);
    }
private:
    SEL sel_;
    id obj_;
    func fun_;
};
```

Hope you can get the idea from this, if not - ask again :)

```
// your new callback type
// boost variant: 
// typedef boost::function<void(const std::string&, const std::string&)> OnComplete;
// c++11 variant
typedef std::function<void(const std::string &, const std::string &)> OnComplete;


// your test function
static void myFunc(const std::string& text, OnComplete completion)
{
    NSLog(@"Try to invoke callback for %s...", text.c_str());
    completion("test", "no_fail");
    NSLog(@"Invoked.");
}

- (void) funCallbackWithSuccess:(const std::string&)success andFail:(const  std::string&)fail
{
    NSLog(@"Called with %s and %s", success.c_str(), fail.c_str());
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // objc_callback is the bridge between objective-c and c++
    myFunc("soviet russia", objc_callback<
        void(const std::string&, const std::string&)>(
            @selector(funCallbackWithSuccess:andFail:), self ) );

    // same thing but with blocks
    myFunc("soviet russia", ^(const std::string& success, const std::string& fail) {
        NSLog(@"Block called with %s and %s", success.c_str(), fail.c_str());
    });
}
```

Good luck.